# Can't remove a row from a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, row

I'm trying to remove an outlier from a data matrix. The original matrix is called `Westdata` and I want to remove row 51.

I've tried the following line of code but it doesn't remove the outlier and the new matrix is identical to the old one.

```
Westdata.Outlier<-Westdata[-51,]



Westdata.Outlier
    State   Region  Pay Spend Area  
20   Mont.  MN 22.5  3.95 West  
21   Wyo.   MN 27.2  5.44 West  
22   N.Mex. MN 22.6  3.40 West  
23   Utah   MN 22.3  2.30 West  
24   Wash.  PA 26.0  3.71 West  
25   Calif. PA 29.1  3.61 West  
26   Hawaii PA 25.8  3.77 West  
46   Idaho  MN 21.0  2.51 West  
47   Colo.  MN 25.9  4.04 West  
48   Ariz.  MN 26.6  2.83 West  
49   Nev.   MN 25.6  2.93 West  
50   Oreg.  PA 25.8  4.12 West  
51   Alaska PA 41.5  8.35 West
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you try to remove the 51th line or the line number 51?

Comment: try: `Westdata[ !rownames(Westdata) == '51', ]`